# How to use Laravel WebSockets for Realtime Data Update

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, real-time, laravel-10

I want to create application that using websocket for realtime data sync. My application has laravel base as backend and react next as frontend, which has an architecture where FE and BE are separate projects. React Next (Frontend) will use socket.io to read the socket URL from Laravel Socket.

How can i create laravel websockets so that the url of laravel socket can be connected using socket.io?

This is my file config that using beyondcode/laravel-websockets

**.env** file for pusher

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=xxx
PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxx
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxx
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

**websockets.php**

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ]
```

**broadcasting.php** for connections pusher

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

**TestWebSocket** Event File

```
class TestWebSocket implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->message = 'Hello world!';
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel('testing'),
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'test-event';
    }
}
```

I already set all of that and when i connect it in postman using websocket `ws://localhost:6001/apps/{PUSHER_APP_KEY}` it can be connected but whatever the message that i send for channel is not returning anything. and when i try to connect it with socket.io in postman using url `http://localhost:6001` or `http://localhost:6001/apps/{PUSHER_APP_KEY}` it returned error **could not connect**

what i must do so i can make laravel websocket that can be connected using socket.io? or what message i must send to postman websocket so i can get the data with event that i listened?

**My goal** is to get realtime data every 5 seconds when client is listening to some event and after 5 second the server socket (backend) is send new data and the client (Frontend) update its data.

Laravel in use => Laravel 10.x